# How to merge the return from one to one relationship

Tags: laravel

I am using one to one relationship in laravel.
I have two models one is User and another is UserDetails.

The relationship is in User model

```
public function userDetails(){

    return $this->hasOne(UserDetail::class); 

}
```

I am calling the models something like that

```
public function index()
{
     $user  = User::find(2);
     $user->user_details = $user->userDetails;
     echo "<pre>"; print_r($user->toArray()); die;
}
```

But I am printing the return getting like this:-

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Joney
    [email] => joney@gmail.com
    [email_verified_at] => 2019-04-29 02:01:03
    [password] => dasDSADASDASDAS
    [status] => Active
    [remember_token] => DSADASd
    [created_at] => 2019-04-29 00:00:00
    [updated_at] => 2018-09-24 02:00:00
    [user_details] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 2
            [address] => Dhampur
            [mobile_number] => 8006009195
            [passport_number] => sasdadasd
            [zip_code] => 201301
            [created_at] => 2019-04-29 06:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2019-04-29 02:00:00
        )

)
```

So I want to get the return after merge the details into an object.

Thanks

Comment: I have Id attribute as a primary key in User model and user_id attributes in user_details table as a foreign key.

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clean what you mean. Are you wanting the output to be an object instead of an array?

Comment: I want to merge user and user_details into one using relationship.

Comment: `User::with('userDetails')->find(2)`

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
    $user  = User::with('userDetails')->find(2);
    $user->user_detail_id = $user->userDetails->id;
    $user->address = $user->userDetails->address;
    $user->mobile_number = $user->userDetails->mobile_number;
    $user->passport_number = $user->userDetails->passport_number;
    $user->zip_code = $user->userDetails->zip_code;
    unset($user->userDetails);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($user->toArray()); die;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I did't want to fetch one by one key.
Is it possible to merge all the keys instead of one by one from userDetails

Comment: then only you have to write `$user  = User::with('userDetails')->find(2);`

Answer (score 1):

This will happen automatically when you load the relationship. You can do this with either [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) or [load()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) depending on whether you have the model or not.

With your example above you would use `with()` as you're getting the user at the same time:

```
$user  = User::with('userDetails')->find(2);
```

Alternatively, if you already had the `User` model then you would use `load()`:

```
 $user  = User::find(2);
 $user->load('userDetails');
```

Now, with all of that said, since you only have the one `User` model and not a collection, you don't need to worry about the (n+1) problem that eager loading solves so you can just access the property and Laravel will automatically getthe information for you e.g.:

```
 $user  = User::find(2);
 $user->user_details;
```

Now if you do `dd($user->toArray())` you will see that the information has been loaded.

---

Just an FYI, instead of using `print_r()` with `die()` and wrapping it in `<pre>` tags, you can use the [dump()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-dump) and [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-dd) helper functions instead.

Comment: @JailendraRajawat Did this not answer your question?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking to merge the user and details info.

I think, it is not possible directly using relationship.

Comment: @JailendraRajawat You wouldn't need to "merge" the data in this case as it would already be part of the object. If you wanting to add other data in general then you could use the `setAttribute()` method.

Comment: @JailendraRajawat Did this answer your question or are you still needing help with your issue? If this did answer your question please may you mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this 
    $user  = User::find(2)

```
echo print-r ($user->userDetails);
```